# SQL dev, find value like variable

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to do something along the lines of:

```
define name1 = '23'
select * from my_db where value1 like '%' + name1 + %'
```

Comment: The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` not `+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close.  Here's a working example.
Use the variable command to register your variable. Then exec, which is a plsql block, to assign the value. Lastly use it in the select as a bind variable. As noted use || for concat operations not +

```
SQL> var name1 varchar2(20)
SQL> exec :name1 := '23';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.



SQL> select * from my_db where value1 like '%' || :name1 || '%';
```

Comment: Not exactly how I'm using it, but I made it work, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Using the with statement allows you to inject the constant into the query.

```
WITH 
name1 AS
(
    SELECT 23 VALUE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM MY_DB
WHERE VALUE1 LIKE '%' || (SELECT VALUE FROM NAME1) || '%'
;
```

What problem are you trying to solve by moving the constant out of the query?

Comment: I'm making a lot of queries where I'm searching with different names and I'm using the names several times